# Zenstruck Foundry Bundle | Reset Database does not work with session table

Tags: symfony, doctrine, phpunit, fixtures

I use Symfony 6.1 , Doctrine, Fixtures, phpunit and Zenstruck Foundry Bundle.

The session is kept in the database.

In a WebTestCase I want to reset the test database and use the ResetDatabase trait for this.

But that doesn't work because the session table isn't deleted with doctrine:schema:drop

As soon as doctrine:schema:create is executed, there is an exception because the session table already exists.

I found out that the session table is on the blacklist and must not be deleted. It also doesn't work with "--full-database".

How do I have to configure the Foundry Bundle or Doctrine to make it work?

Please excuse my bad English

I found this, but unfortunately it doesn't offer a solution.
https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/8976

Answer (score 0):

I guess I found the mistake.
Someone created a session entity. :(

This seems to affect the behavior of doctrine:schema:create.